# Javascript variable equals specific URL

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement, anchor

I'm trying to get this conditional statement to work, but having no luck

```
<body onload="HashTagInsert()">
    function HashTagInsert() {
        var hash="window.location";
        if (hash==="http://www.address.com#anchor1") 
        {
            document.getElementById("insert-text").innerHTML="<h2>Title</h2><p>body text</p>";
        }
        else if (hash==="http://www.url.com/foler/code/page.html#anchor2")
        {
            document.getElementById("insert-text").innerHTML="<h2>Title</h2><p>body text</p>";
        }
        else ()
        {
            document.getElementById("insert-text").innerHTML="something else text"
        }
    }
</body>
```

Comment: hash is going to equal "window.location" and not the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `hash` variable to be the value of the `window.location` object, then **don't put quotes around the object name** as that will turn it into a string literal.

```
 var hash = window.location;
```

---

I recommend not calling the variable `hash` though, as that could be confused with `window.location.hash`, which contains the fragment ID component of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add quotes around window.location.

```
var hash = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare your current window location with some string you need to set the "hash" variable correctly:

```
var hash = window.location;
```

but I am not sure if I got your problem. 
In case that your javascript can not set your html properly, there is also a timing problem. It depends when your javascript gets called. Before or after your DOM has been rendered. Because if your javascript is executed before your DOM (and your element '#insert-text') is rendered, you wont be able to select this DOM element.

And ... but this is perhaps just my opinion, is is pretty uncool to have masses of if / else if / else constructions in your code.

You might want to map some url and text so that you do not need to make your life harder than it is.

for example:

```
var html;
var mapping = {
    "http://www.address.com#anchor1":"<h2>Yeah</h2><p>Baby</p>",
    "http://www.address.com#anchor2":"<h2>Cool</h2><p>Tomato</p>",
    "default": "<h2>Woops</h2><p>Honolulu rocks</p>"
}

mapping[window.location.href] ? html = mapping[window.location.href] : html = mapping['default'];

document.getElementById("insert-text").innerHTML=html;
```